# linq return using Tuple

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

hi i just upgraded to Framework 4.0 and added relationship foreign key to my database. I would like to join 2 table `User and Staff` and return back to UI. Staff table has the UserId. Having to say that, whenever the user name is clicked on the datagridview, i would like to display out User and Staff data to all the textbox.

I do this using Tuple

```
   public IEnumerable<Tuple<User, Staff>> Get()
    {
        using (qDataContext db = new qDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var r = from u in db.Users
                        join s in db.Staffs on u.Id equals s.UserId
                        select new Tuple<User, Staff>(u, s);

                return r;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

But in UI, how should i do the binding? 
`gvUser.DataSource = user.Get();`

FYI, The gridview is just display the username. Staff table will store the password, datejoined fields..

By the way, do i still need to join tables since i have already added foreign key reference to the tables.. i am thinking of it should smart enough to return me User.Staff.Password

---

**EDIT**
this is what i found..
i have added relationship foreign key to my database. 
and the code below is already able to return me User and Staff data as Staff.UserId is pointed to UserId
`And i don have to use the TUPLE to return those object :)!!`

```
 public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        using (ZebraDataContext db = new ZebraDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var r = from u in db.Users
                        select u;
                        //join s in db.Staffs on u.Id equals s.UserId
                        //select new Tuple<User, Staff>(u, s);

                return r.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, i have trouble when i bind to the GUI datagridview.

```
 private void InitializeData()
    {
       gvUser.DataSource = user.Get();
    }
```

This code able to shows me the User data. But how do i get back the Staff data when i do the `gvUser_RowEnter`?

private void gvUser_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex <= 0) return;

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvUser.SelectedRows)
        {
            User user = row.DataBoundItem as User;
            txtName.Text = user.Name;
            txtAddress.Text = user.Address;
            txtPhone.Text = user.Phone;
            txtPhone2.Text = user.Phone2;
            txtRemark.Text = user.Remarks;

            txtPassword.Text = user.Staffs.First().Password;

        }
    }
```

`txtPassword.text =  user.Staffs.First().Password`   < == failed with this error 
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.

when i add watch the Staff object in User. i can see the data in the hidden
((User)(row.DataBoundItem)).Staffs.entities.Items  this has the staff data ..

Answer (score 3):

Rather than returning a `Tuple`, wouldn't returning an anonymous object do the trick? It might look something like this:

```
var r = from u in db.Users
    select new { u.Name, 
                 u.Address,
                 ...,
                 (from s in db.Staffs select s.Password where u.Id == s.UserId) 
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to bind complex types you should think about DescriptorProviders. Here is some similar example http://www.ureader.com/msg/14411105.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would prefer if don use third party libarry